# "Cannot format given Object as a Date" error when formatting google api client DateTime

Tags: java, android, datetime, simpledateformat

I need to convert the DateTime object, of google api client package, to a simple string. Should be easy, but i am new to android.

```
com.google.api.client.util.DateTime  date = new com.google.api.client.util.DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
String dateAsISOString = df.format(date);
```

This gives the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a
>   Date

I guess DateFormat should be from some google package too, but can't find where.

Comment: You should be using `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to use `SimpleDateFormat` with wrong `Date` Object.

You should be using `java.util.Date` instead if you want to make use of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
String dateAsISOString = df.format(date);
System.out.println(dateAsISOString);
```